# Como proteger as rotas no angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routes, angular-8

Estou migrando uma aplicação do angularJs pro angular 8 e uma grande dificuldade que estou tendo é no sistema de roteamento, na minha aplicação e obrigatório esta logado para todas as rotas excerto pras rotas de login e registro, no angularJs eu fazia essa regra no app.run() eu verificava se o usuário estava logado e permitia ou negava o redirecionamento pra rota, o código baixo tem um exemplo simples de como isso era feito

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/", {
    templateUrl : "main.htm"
  })
  .when("/red", {
    templateUrl : "red.htm"
  })
  .when("/green", {
    templateUrl : "green.htm"
  })
  .when("/blue", {
    templateUrl : "blue.htm"
  });
});

app.run(function(authService) {
   //aqui eu fazia a regra que se ele nao estivesse logado eu jogava ele pra rota de login
});
```

no angular 8 não estou conseguindo restringir o usuário da maneira certa pelo frontend apenas pelo backend, e eu queria fazer isso pelo front, pois meu servido não aguenta muitas requisições, então pra mim e inviável toda vez que o usuário acessa uma rota eu ir la no backend verificar se ele esta logado e mandar a confinação, eu já tenho o token e o dados dos usuário guardado em uma variável global dentro de um service, porem só estou conseguindo restringir o usuário depois que ele já acessou a rota e já iniciou a controller então eu verifico se ele tem o token na variável global e se não tiver eu jogo ele pra outra rota, e eu queria que isso fosse feito já no modulo que fornece as rotas como eu fazia no angularJS, isso e possível?

Comment: pesquise por coisas **canActivate** e **[AuthGuard]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira correta de restringir rotas é implementar a interface `CanActivate`, que deve ser utilizada em um routeguard. O tutorial que eu utilizei para implementar este comportamento foi [este](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3).

***app/can-activate-route.guard.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateRouteGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(public router: Router) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        //implementar este método
    }
}
```

***src/app/app.module.ts***

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CanActivateRouteGuard } from './can-activate-route.guard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    //componentes
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // declaração de modulos
  ],
  providers: [
    CanActivateRouteGuard //importar como provider este route guard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***src/app/app-routing.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PublicComponent } from './public/public.component';
import { RestrictComponent } from './restric/restrict.component';
import { CanActivateRouteGuard } from './can-activate-route.guard';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path : 'public', component: PublicComponent},
  { path : 'restrict', component: RestrictComponent, canActivate: [CanActivateRouteGuard]},
  { path : '', redirectTo: '/public', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

O tutorial que segui é em uma versão mais antiga, porém eu consegui implementar com a versão atual do angular. `(9.1)`.

Existe um tutorial oficial do angular, [mais informações aqui](https://angular.io/guide/router).